# Simple permissions question

Tags: development, permissions, roles

I know how to grant someone certain role to a list (contribute or read for example) using C# such as:

```
                    SPRoleAssignment userRoleAssignmentCont = new SPRoleAssignment(allUsers);
                    SPRoleDefinition userRoleDefinitionCont = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
                    userRoleAssignmentCont.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(userRoleDefinitionCont);
                    list.RoleAssignments.Add(userRoleAssignmentCont);
```

But how do I do the exact same thing but instead of the list I grant permission to a group of people/permissions list. So basically - the user/users in question will be granted contribute permissions to add, remove or update people to a certain group (special administrators for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
public void addPermissionToGroup()
{
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite:5050/");
    SPWeb spWeb = site.OpenWeb();
    string permissionName = "Read";
    string groupName = "Project Manager";

 try
 {
    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(spWeb.SiteGroups[groupName]);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spWeb.RoleDefinitions[permissionName]);

    if (!spWeb.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        spWeb.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

    spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
    spWeb.Update();
}
catch (Exception _exception)
{
    throw _exception;
}
finally
{
    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
}
```

For adding user to Group:

```
public void AddUsers(string groupname, string username)
{
 try
 {
     SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
     {
           // Gets a new security context using SHAREPOINT\system
           using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
           {
                 using (SPWeb thisWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                 {
                      thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                      SPUser Name = thisWeb.EnsureUser(username);
                      thisWeb.Groups[groupname].AddUser(Name);
                      thisWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                 }
            }
  });

 }

 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   //Log error here.
  }
 }
```

Set GroupA as owner of GroupB

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://site02"))
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
   SPGroup visitors = web.SiteGroups["GroupB"];
   SPGroup members = web.SiteGroups["GroupA"];
   visitors.Owner = (SPMember)members;
   visitors.Update();
   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was possibly wrong. I want to give a user permission to manage user groups (add users to a particular group etc.)

Comment: Please look the edited answer here you have to pass username, and group.

Comment: another solution could be by "/UserGroup.asmx" also.

Comment: This still hasn't really addressed my initial problem. Thanks a lot for your help so far but what I'm looking to do is give a user group permission to manage a user group. So if I belong to GroupA - I am permitted to add/remove/update users belonging to GroupB.

Comment: ok, I got your question, for that you have to set the GroupB owner property with the name of GroupA. Editing my answser with code.